# Subgroups of $ D_8 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$D_8 =\{ e, r, r^2, r^3, s, rs, r^2s, r^3s\} $ where r is a rotation by $ \frac{\pi } {2} $ anticlockwise and s is a reflection. Then according to my book, there are 10 subgroups, four of which are $\{ e,rs\},\{e, r^2 s \}, \{e, r^3 s\}, \{e, r^2 , rs, r ^3 s \}$.

I don't quite how they are subgroups. For instance for $\{e,rs\}$, if we consider $ (rs)^2 = r^2 s^2 = r^2 $ which is not in this subgroup.

Thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(rs)^2$ does not mean $r^2s^2$.  It means $(rs)(rs)$, which by associativity is equal to $ r(sr)s$.  In $D_8$ we have $sr = r^3s$, so $r(sr)s = r(r^3s)s = r^4s^2 = e$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand where it went wrong